# Adjust the output width of R Markdown HTML output

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I am producing an HTML output but I am having issues with the output width of R code output.

I'm able to adjust the figure width with no difficulty but when I try to write a data table or the factor loadings, R is outputting at a fixed width which is only about a third of my screen width.  This results in the columns of the table being split up rather than all of the columns displayed in a single table.

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

# Title

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width=16, fig.height=6}
x = matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10)
x
plot(x)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I think something like `fig.width = \\linewidth` in the chunk options might help, but I defer to better experts than me

Comment: I'm ok with the figure.width, that can be controlled in my chunk options just fine.  The problem is the blocks of text/table output being fixed.  Thanks for pointing out the \\linewidth which will be useful in the future.

Comment: I suggest you post some reproducible sample code to show how the offending plots are created. Maybe if you look in the help manual for your plotting function there will be some dummy data and code samples you can use? It will probably help a lot.

Comment: It is not the plots which are offending.  The figures are printing just how I would like them.  It's the TEXT/TABLES which are not using the full width of the screen.  I can supply an example if it is really required.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Add this at the start of your document:

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(width = SOME-REALLY-BIG-VALUE)
```
````

Obviously, replace SOME-REALLY-BIG-VALUE with a number. But do you really want to do all that horizontal scrolling?

Your output is probably being wrapped somewhere around 80 characters or so.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much.  It was even more simple than I imagined!

Comment: And notice that the success of this will depend on the css theme. So this will work with Rstudios default theme, and with the cerulian theme, but if you choose the theme *readable* the text will be mangled despite options(width=400).

Comment: Thanks @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1

Comment: To provide a solution in the case of the comment by @RasmusLarsen ,  I was very happy with the inline style in this answer------ . https://stackoverflow.com/a/36846864/1518460

Answer (score 32):

Also, you can temporarily change the local R options for a code chunk:

````
```{r my-chunk, R.options = list(width = SOME-BIG-VALUE)}

```
````

Comment: Underrated answer. This is more likely to be useful (at least for me) as I usually want to override the sensible defaults only for one particular code chunk.