# R markdown summary output

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to keep all the columns of the summary output in same line, do you have a solution?
[as shown in the picture, the last column goes to a new line, how to avoid it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRmcH.png)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a code example, I can't help edit the code. In your Rmarkdown initial set up chunk, put the code below

````
```
{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(width = 1000)
```
````

the `width = 1000` will need to be adjusted to meet your needs.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385696/adjust-the-output-width-of-r-markdown-html-output) is a link that might help you get more information